# problem in retrieving custom customer attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, custom-attributes

I created a custom attribute for customer module using below install script:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "mobile",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Mobile Number",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => "Mobile Number"

        ));

        $attribute = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "mobile");


$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'mobile',
    '999'  //sort_order
);

$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
//$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
                ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
                ->setData("is_system", 0)
                ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
                ->setData("is_visible", 1)
                ->setData("sort_order", 100)
                ;
        $attribute->save();
$installer->endSetup();
```

new `mobile` attribute created in `eav_attribute` table. But while retrieving in customer edit form using below, `mobile` attribute is missing there.

```
<?php
     Mage::log(print_r($this->getCustomer()->getData(), true), null, 'customer.log');
?>
```

Below is the output I got:

```
(
            [entity_id] => 23
            [entity_type_id] => 1
            [attribute_set_id] => 0
            [website_id] => 1
            [email] => pop@pop.com
            [group_id] => 1
            [increment_id] => 
            [store_id] => 1
            [created_at] => 2015-10-18T11:56:26+04:00
            [updated_at] => 2015-10-18 11:56:26
            [is_active] => 1
            [disable_auto_group_change] => 0
            [created_in] => Default Store View
            [firstname] => Anto
            [lastname] => Jaskaran
            [password_hash] => 7bda12fd6b2ecea227d55f088f5b653e:FBVp10XN6FZWBXZ8v0waWazWAw5KYreX
        )
```

Comment: You need to save a value for your new attribute in order to see it in the log. Does your attribute field appear in the admin form?

Comment: @Marius thanks for the reply. In admin only a blank text box is showing. Not the value.

Comment: @Marius thanks for the hint. I corrected it. Now it is proper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments....
An attribute appears on the customer instance if there is a value for that attribute in the database.
You need to save the customer instance from the backend first and then it will appear. in the `_data` array.