# How to get value of Custom attribute?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-attributes

I have created a custom attribute "test_emails" by as following Store-->Store Attributes-->Add new Attribute, I put attribute code "test_emails" , that appeared in table "eav_attribute" and the field values in "customer_address_entity_text" as shown in Pic, Where 668 is attribute id form table "eav_attribute" for "test_emails", how can I get these values [image]

Comment: need get in customer address model?

Comment: Can you see the attribute in admin ? Looks like you have used some extension to create customer attribute.

Comment: @Abdul"need get in customer address model? " what do you meant?, I am new to magento, can you guide me?

Comment: @Prateek yes I can see them in Customer-->Manage Customer-->Customer Information-->Address

Comment: Currently I have two address for Single customer, due to this you can see two rows In pic entity_id (3663,2557) are address id's for that user

Comment: Which place your geting value of Custom attribute?

Comment: @Abdul as I said early,  I can see them in Customer-->Manage Customer-->Customer Information-->Address, but I don't Know how these are appearing, I have to use them some where else

Comment: have you created attribute using any script?

Comment: No, just followed the order as described above in post

Comment: Please create bellow way

Comment: Please guide me through it

Comment: pls check in answer

Comment: Looks like you have a customer address attribute, not customer attribute. You'll need to get address object from customer first, then you can retrieve your custom attribute.

Comment: This might help you in the direction : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86851/problem-in-retrieving-custom-customer-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add bellow code in php file(abc.php) on magento root folder and run in browser and see admin side  Customer-->Manage Customer-->Customer Information-->Address,

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');

class ABDUL
{
    public function index()    
    {
        $installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

        $entityTypeId     = $installer->getEntityTypeId('customer_address');
        $attributeSetId   = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
        $attributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

        $installer->addAttribute('customer_address', 'company_name', array(
            'input'         => 'text',
            'type'          => 'varchar',
            'label'         => 'Company Name',
            'visible'       => 1,
            'required'      => 0,
            'user_defined' => 1,
        ));

        $installer->addAttributeToGroup(
         $entityTypeId,
         $attributeSetId,
         $attributeGroupId,
         'company_name',
         '22'  //sort_order
        );

        $oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer_address', 'company_name');
        $oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer_address','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address'));
        $oAttribute->save();
        $installer->endSetup();

        echo "Customer address attribute has been created successfully";
    } 

}

$obj = new ABDUL();
$obj->index();
?>
```

Comment: What does this code do,

Comment: I need to read the value, not to crate the new attribute